# How do I tell which player has set a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, mods, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-spigot

How do I tell what player has set a block?
If there is a plugin for it, that would be easy, but I understand that that is probably not an option. If so, could someone show me how to create a plugin? I know how to program Java, I just don't specifically know how to create a plugin.

Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a plugin for this, it is called the [Eagle Eye Plugin](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/eagle-eye) This plugin tells

1. Who has logged in and out of your server
2. Who has placed and broken blocks
3. Who has used items and or blocks (e.g. Sword, Chest, Furnace, Pickaxe, etc.)
4. Much more!

   I understood what you asked but please try to give a better example of the question you are asking and before you ask a question try to google it because I found the Eagle Eye plugin right as I searched your question.  Please let me know if this helped you!

Comment: I actually did try to Google my question, but I couldn't find anything fsr. Yeah I knew that I didn't phrase the question in the best way, but I didn't bother rephrasing it, because I thought people would know what I meant anyways. But thanks for the feedback!

Comment: No problem :D I came to this website to get help and to give help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more complete solution, I suggest using [LogBlocks](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/logblock). It has been the *de facto* logging facility since the early days of Bukkit. Apart from logging various block events and chest access, it has tools for rolling back changes. There is a learning curve and it is best used with a MySQL database (as opposed to SQLite).